# Anyone know if CoinHive uses the new Monero hashing algorithm?

Tags: cryptonight, hash-verification, coin-hive

When I visit https://coinhive.com/ , I see a "Start Mining" button at the center of their page.  I know recently Monero changed its hashing algorithm to be CryptoNight v1 (variant 1).  Does Coinhive use their new algorithm ?  Their site gives no documentation about this.  If they don't, then is it just a charade when you click the "Start Mining" button?

Comment: Cryptonight v1, not v7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They announced support on Twitter back in April:
https://twitter.com/coinhive_com/status/981102585460543489